# CheckBoxFor value does not change when the user ticks the box

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, checkboxfor

I have a checkBoxFor to be used on a JQuery form and bound to my model, My issue is that when a user checks or unchecks the box the value used for some Client side validation is always true and the value used for server side validation is always false. Why is my check box not updating the value?

**View:**

```
 <form id="companyForm">
    <fieldset>
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.allCompany, new { @checked = "checked" })
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.allCompany)
        </p>
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.hierarchyValidation)
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.hierarchyValidation)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.hierarchyValidation)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.hierarchyValidation)
        </p>
        <!-- Allow form submission with keyboard without duplicating the dialog button -->
        <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**View Model**

public class AXAddRoleViewModel
    {

```
    public bool allCompany { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "HierarchySelectList")]
    [IsEmptyAttribute("hierarchyValidation", "allCompany")]
    public string hierarchyValidation { get; set; }
}
```

**Client side validation:**

```
var isApplicationValid = $('#application').valid();
var isHierarchyValid = $('#hierarchyValidation').valid();

if (isHierarchyValid && isCompanyValid) {
    var roleName = $("#roleName").val();
    var hierarchy = $("#hierarchyValidation").val().toString();

    var data = {
        "reasons": message,
        "hierarchyValidation": hierarchy
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert("Success");
        },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Custom Validator attribute:**

```
public enum Comparison
{
    IsEmpty,
    ContainsValue
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class IsEmptyAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    private const string DefaultErrorMessage = "{0} Is required if a value from {1} is not selected.";

    public string ValueLabel { get; private set; }
    public string CompaniesValue { get; set; }

    public IsEmptyAttribute(string valueLabel, string companiesValue)
        : base(DefaultErrorMessage)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(valueLabel))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("otherProperty");
        }
        ValueLabel = valueLabel;
        CompaniesValue = companiesValue;
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return string.Format(ErrorMessageString, ValueLabel, CompaniesValue);
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value,
                          ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var allCompaniesSelected = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType()
                                   .GetProperty(CompaniesValue);
        var allCompaniesSelectedValue = allCompaniesSelected
                              .GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

        if (Convert.ToBoolean(allCompaniesSelectedValue) == false)
        {
            if (value == null)
            {

                return new ValidationResult(
                    FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
            }
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var clientValidationRule = new ModelClientValidationRule()
        {
            ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName()),
            ValidationType = "isempty"
        };

        clientValidationRule.ValidationParameters.Add("companiesvalue", CompaniesValue);

        return new[] { clientValidationRule };
    }
}
```

**Custom Validator javascript:**

```
(function ($) {
    $.validator.addMethod("isempty", function (value, element, params) {
        if (this.optional(element)) {
            var allCompanies = $('#addRoleCompany_allCompany')
            if (allCompanies.val() == false) {
                var otherProp = $('#addRoleCompany_' + params)
                return (otherProp.val() != value);
            }
        }
        return true;
    });
    $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addSingleVal("isempty", "otherproperty");

}(jQuery));
```

Can anybody tell me where should I look to find the issue and what the problem is?

Thank you for any help with this problem.

Comment: The `value` attribute of the checkbox generated is `true` and its associated hidden input is `false` (this is so it can correctly be bound to a `boolean` value on post back). What do you mean _when I try to do some data validation the value is always false_?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Sorry I didn't make the issue too clear in my question I have Edited it now. The form I am using has a multiselect that needs to be required if the check box  is false. but when I try to validate the client side is always true and the server side is always false.

Comment: How do you validate it client side? - show your code. And the value of  `allCompany` will be either `true` or `false` (server side) depending on whether the  checkbox is checked or not (unless you have disabled the checkbox)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I just use the jquery: `var isHierarchyValid = $('#addRoleCompany_hierarchyValidation').valid();` I will add the full code once I have simplified the solution.

Comment: Hi @StephenMuecke I have added a simplified version of the code I have been using, and I have got it to compile. My custom validator is where I now suspect the issues are arising. Thank you for any help and advice you can give me.

Comment: Possible problem is `var isApplicationValid = $('#application').valid();` Are you calling `validate()` on the form first?

Comment: @StephenMuecke The code has been working fine until I have tried to add the checkbox to my custom validator, maybe I need to compare the validator differently but the rest of the validation is seems to work fine this way. Do you have a better solution though?

Comment: I don't have time to test you validation attribute now, but have you through of just using [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIfTrue]` attribute (tried and tested). Note - I also suspect you have a problem because your rendering `hierarchyValidation` as a hidden control which by default will not be validated by jquery-validate-unobtrusive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I had overlooked the fact that I need to pass the value from Jquery after checking if the box is ticked or not.

A simple mistake. Thank you everyone who helped solve this with me.